# launching a program with cpu affinity AND priority presets

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, priority, affinity

I'm trying to create a shortcut for Traktor pro 2 which assigns the programs priority level and core assignments. In this case i'm trying to launch Traktor with realtime priority, set to function on cores 2-7.

so far i can only get one or the other setting to stick.

my target looks like so

C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start /realtime "Traktor 2" "C:\Program Files\Native Instruments\Traktor 2\Traktor.exe" & /c "traktor 2" /affinity FC "C:\Program Files\Native Instruments\Traktor 2\Traktor.exe"

I'm defintely a layman so i'm sure i have misplaced a qoutation mark or something simple, but no matter what i try i can't get the affinity setting and the realtime priority setting to both activate when i click the shortcut

any help would be appreciated. thanks so much!

Comment: Setting anything to the realtime priority class is NOT recommended. Your program may interfere with the operation of important system functions - like drivers using user mode driver frameworks, or any drivers using kernel threads.

Comment: hence the affinity setting for preventing traktor from running on cores 0 and 1, where from my understanding and reading around the internet, is where all those system and kernal functions happen.

Comment: Sorry but that's incorrect. System and kernel functions can and do happen on any  CPU or LP. Setting affinity is usually a bad idea - when you limit the choices that the scheduler can make, it makes poorer choices.

Comment: okay thanks but lets say, for whatever reason that seems illogical, my computer processes an audio stream glitch free ONLY when i have my affinity and priority set up like i mentioned, how would i set up the target for the shortcut?

Comment: I'd suggest you have a deeper problem. There's no way Traktor Pro should need that much coddling.

Answer (score -1):

You may try to use Process Explorer to check result.

This Microsoft tool can set the affinity and priority of a process.

Download it from here

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer